# OpenShift - Connecting to a scaled gear's MySQL cartridge from another gear

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a Node.js gear (not scaled) and a PHP gear (scaled) with a MySQL cartridge. I want to connect to the MySQL cartridge from the Node.js app.

The documentation for this is not concise and seems outdated, but from what I've gathered I need to forward my MySQL port to the Node.js app.

I created a public/private key pair on the MySQL gear using `ssh-keygen -f $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/mykey`. Next I added the contents of `mykey.pub` into my RedHat account's Settings > Public Keys section. Next I tried to copy the private key to the Node.js server using `scp $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/mykey 59bc0f5c50014651f7020097@nodegear-mydomain.rhcloud.com:~/app-root/data/.` but this gave me a permissions error, so next I tried `scp -i $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/mykey $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/mykey 59bc0f5c50014651f7020097@nodegear-mydomain.rhcloud.com:~/app-root/data/.` and I think that did what it needed to, but I'm not sure.

Does that seem right? From here what do I do? And is there an easier way to connect to a database cartridge on another gear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, well it seems most of the information I dug up about connecting to a database on another gear was wrong. You don't need to forward ports or anything like that. Just get the host, port, user, and password of your database cartridge (ssh into your gear with the db and run `env | grep -i mysql`) and use them for your db connection string.